# JavaScript Event Loop out of order execution

Tags: javascript, settimeout, event-loop

I was trying out an example from a book to confirm how JavaScript event loop works, here is the code

```
const baz = () => console.log("baz");
const bar = () => console.log("bar");

const foo = () => {
    console.log("foo");
    setTimeout(bar, 0);
    baz();
}
foo();
```

It is straightforward how setTimeout works here (executed out of order) output is

```
foo
baz
bar
```

What I don't understand is the order when I added one line

```
const baz = () => console.log("baz");
const bar = () => console.log("bar");

const foo = () => {
    console.log("foo");
    setTimeout(bar, 0);
    baz();
}
setTimeout(baz, 0); // this somehow runs before foo() is finished
foo();
```

Output is

```
foo
baz
baz 
bar
```

How come the second setTimeout rins before foo() is done?

Comment: Consider the event loop as a queue, your code inserts something to do later before calling foo, call foo, foo **appends** something else to the queue, foo ends, the event loop extracts from the queue the first submission

Comment: Ah, I see I get it now many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an explanation from an event-loop perspective.

You can visualize the call-stack, which is used to keep track of whereabouts we are in a program at a given point in time. When you call a function, we push it onto the stack, and when we return/complete a function, we pop it off the top of the stack. Initially, the stack is empty.

When you first run your code, your main "script" will be pushed onto the stack, and will be popped off the stack once the script has finished executing:

```
Stack:
------
- Main()   // <-- indicates that we're in the main script
```

we then define a few functions `baz`, `bar` and `foo`, and eventually reach our first function invocation, `setTimeout(baz, 0)`,  and so, we push it onto the stack:

```
Stack:
------
- setTimeout(baz, 0)
- Main()
```

`setTimeout()` kicks off a web-api which after `0`ms enqueues your `baz` callback onto the *task queue*. After `setTimeout` has passed off its work to the web-api, its job is complete, and so it has finished its work and can be popped off the stack:

```
Stack:
------
- Main()

Task Queue: (Front <--- Back)
baz
```

It is the event loop's job to take tasks from the task queue and push them onto the stack when the stack is *empty*. Currently, the stack is not empty as we're still in the main script, so `baz()` has not executed yet. The next function invocation we meet is `foo()`, so we push this onto our stack:

```
Stack:
------
- foo()
- Main()

Task Queue: (Front <--- Back)
baz
```

Foo then calls the console object's `log()` method, which is also pushed onto the stack:

```
Stack:
------
- log("foo")
- foo()
- Main()

Task Queue: (Front <--- Back)
baz
```

**This logs `"foo"`**, and `log()` is popped off of the stack as it has finished its work. We then continue stepping through the function foo. We now encounter a function call to `setTimeout(bar, 0);`. This, much like the first function call, pushes `setTimeout(bar, 0)` onto the stack. This spins off a web-api which adds `bar` to the task queue. `setTimeout(bar, 0)` is also complete once it has handed off its work to the web-api, so it also gets popped off the stack (see second and third ascii-diagrams for these steps), leaving us with:

```
Stack:
------
- foo()
- Main()

Task Queue: (Front <--- Back)
baz, bar
```

Finally, we arrive the last line in the function `foo` which calls `baz()`. This pushes `baz()` onto the call stack, and then pushes `log("baz")` to the top of the call stack, which **logs "baz"**. So far, we have logged "foo" and then "baz". After baz has been logged `log()` is popped off the stack and so is `baz()` as it has finished.

Once the last line in `foo()` is finished, we implicitly return, popping `foo()` off the stack, leaving us with `Main()`. Once we have returned from foo, our control/execution is returned back to the main script after where `foo()` was invoked. As there are no more functions to call in our script, we pop `Main()` off the stack, leaving us with:

```
Stack:
------
<EMPTY>

Task Queue: (Front <--- Back)
baz, bar
```

Now that the stack is empty, the event-loop can come in and handle `baz` and `bar` in the task-queue. First is takes `baz` out of the queue and pushes it onto the stack, which then invokes `log("baz")`, pushing `log` onto the stack and then **logging "baz"**. Once the log is complete, `log` and `baz` are popped off the stack leaving it empty again:

```
Stack:
------
<EMPTY>

Task Queue: (Front <--- Back)
bar
```

Now that the stack is empty again, the event-loop takes the first task from the queue (ie: `bar`) and pushes in onto the stack. `bar` then calls `log("bar")`, which adds `log("bar")` to the stack, as well as **logs "bar"** to the console. Once the logging is complete, `log()` and `bar()` are both popped off of the stack.

As a result, the output of your logs are printed in the following order (see bolded logs above):

```
"foo"
"baz"
"baz"
"bar"
```

Some good resources on the event loop and call stack can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=1293s&ab_channel=JSConf), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&t=1031s&ab_channel=JSConf) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack#:%7E:text=A%20call%20stack%20is%20a,from%20within%20that%20function%2C%20etc.).

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep in mind that all the synchronous code will run first, then the asynchronous code. (`setTimeout` will always queue up asynchronous actions, even if set with a timeout of 0.)

So, with this in mind the order of events is as follows:

- register an asynchronous call to `baz()`
- synchronously output `foo`
- register an asynchronous call to `bar()`
- synchronously call `baz()`, outputting `baz`

Knowing the sync stuff runs first, we get `foo` then `baz` first.

Then our async events run, outputting `baz` and `bar` in turn.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it clearly if you separate the asyncronous operations from the rest of code:

```
const baz = () => console.log("baz");
const bar = () => console.log("bar");

const foo = () => {
    console.log("foo");
    setTimeout(bar, 0);
    baz();
}
setTimeout(baz, 0); // this somehow runs before foo() is finished
foo();
```

If we extract the `setTimeout` functions we will have:

```
const baz = () => console.log("baz");
const bar = () => console.log("bar");

const foo = () => {
    console.log("foo");
    // setTimeout(bar, 0);
    baz();
}
// setTimeout(baz, 0); // this somehow runs before foo() is finished
foo();
```

that logs the first two lines:

```
foo
baz
```

During the first loop the asyncronous functions defined in `setTimeout` have been added to the next loop, so we have to execute them:

```
setTimeout(baz, 0);
setTimeout(bar, 0);
```

Resulting in the next two lines of log:

```
baz 
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the `setTimeout(baz, 0)` function, it's going to the call stack, then to the timers phase in the Event Loop, and wait there.

After you call the `foo()` function, which inserting into the call stack the  `console.log("foo")`, `setTimeout(bar, 0)` and `baz()`.
As the `console.log("foo")` is a synchronous operation, it is executed immediately and you see `"foo"` in the output.
`setTimeout(bar, 0)` goes over to the timers phase in the Event Loop and wait.
Then executing the `baz()` function, which in turn launches `console.log("baz")`, and you see the `"baz"` in the output.
After executing the synchronous operations, and the call stack is empty, and the wait for the timers is over, starting to execute the callbacks from the `setTimeouts`.

`setTimeout(baz, 0)` -> `baz` -> `console.log("baz")` = `"baz"` in the otput

and after that

`setTimeout(bar, 0)` -> `bar` -> `console.log("bar")` = `"bar"` in the otput